# How to do math operation on objects attributes?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have list of objects with weather values `List<Weather> weatherList = new ArrayList();`

on the list I have two objects:

```
{
    "latitude": 13.699444,
    "longitude": 12.676667,
    "timezone": "",
    "daily": {
        "data": [
            {
                "time": 1586037600,
                "sunriseTime": 1586059620,
                "sunsetTime": 1586107860,
                "moonPhase": 0.41,
                "temperatureHigh": 8.36,
                "temperatureHighError": 3.58,
                "temperatureLow": 3.72,

            }
        ]
    },
    "offset": 2
}
```

and

```
{
    "latitude": 11.699444,
    "longitude": 10.676667,
    "timezone": "",
    "daily": {
        "data": [
            {
                "time": 1586037600,
                "sunriseTime": 1586059620,
                "sunsetTime": 1586107860,
                "moonPhase": 0.41,
                "temperatureHigh": 12.36,
                "temperatureHighError": 6.58,
                "temperatureLow": 3.72,

            }
        ]
    },
    "offset": 2
}
```

Of course I have all getters and setters. 
I need to pick up this object which have bigger value (temperatureHigh/temperatureLow)/2. 
I tried

```
Double resultNumber;
for(Weather weather:  weatherList){
     resultNumber = ((weather.getDaily().getData().get(0).getTemperatureLow()/weather.getDaily().getData().get(0).getTemperatureHigh())/2);
//and here I got result for only one object
}
```

How should I do it? Should I add to lets say:  `Map<resultNumber,WeatherObject>`? and get my value? 
Or is any option to use streams and lambdas here?

Comment: By "pick up this object which have bigger value (temperatureHigh/temperatureLow)/2", do you mean that you want to choose the object that have such bigger value over the other?

Comment: yes exactly. 
First one : (8.36/3.58)/2 = 1.167
Second one: (12.36/6.58)2 = 0,94. 
So I would like to choose first object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just declare another variable that stores the current value (temperatureHigh/temperatureLow)/2. Then, you compare it to the resultNumber that you stored. If this temporary number is larger, you update both the resultNumber and resultWeather to the current value and weather.

```
Double temp;
Double resultNumber; 
Weather resultWeather; 
for(Weather weather:  weatherList){
    temp = ((weather.getDaily().getData().get(0).getTemperatureLow()/weather.getDaily().getData().get(0).getTemperatureHigh())/2);
    if(resultNumber == null || Double.compare(resultNumber,temp) < 0) {
        resultNumber = temp;
        resultWeather = weather;
    }
}
//at this point resultWeather holds the weather with the highest value
```

Or if there are only two weather in weatherList, you can just do an if else statement which compares the value of the two weather, and stores the weather with a bigger value into another weather object.

```
double value1 = weatherList.get(0).(the operation to get the value for the first weather);
double value2 = weatherList.get(1).(the operation to get the value for the other weather);
Weather resultWeather;
if(value1 > value2){
    resultWeather = weatherList.get(0);
}
else{
    resultWeather = weatherList.get(1);
}
//at this point resultWeather holds the weather with the higher value of the two
```